# nginx, alias, php-fpm = File not Found

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, alias

I'm trying to set up nginx with DAViCal.
However, I'm getting a "File not Found" with a "FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" in the log.
Looks like something is wrong with my aliasing but I sure can't figure it out.

My virtual host:

```
server {
listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /var/www-data;
index index.html index.htm index.shtml index.php;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name just.a.server;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    ssi on;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    #try_files  $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}

location /kalender {
    alias  /usr/share/davical/htdocs;
}
```

}

My fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```

Looking forward to your replies.

Comment: htdocs is 777 btw

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fixed it. Turns out, you have to include the php bit under every location block.

```
location /calender {
    alias  /usr/share/davical/htdocs;

        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, there be a way to "include" this otherwise you need to change the php stuff for every location!

Comment: this will not work on every OS and every version. it all depends on `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` and the fact is it set in `fastcgi_params` or `fastcgi.conf` see [this](https://serverfault.com/a/922596/176452) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28494798/2450431)

Answer (score 1):

I found that moving my php matching block above my root location block worked just fine.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location / {
    root /Users/YOU/Projects/PROJECT;
}
```

Comment: Does this work for an alias though? This does not answer the original question.

Comment: not relevant. nginx always tries regex location blocks first.

Comment: @Geoffrey yes this does work for alias